# Haskell function example, why infinite list doesnt stop

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Why doesnt map sqrt[1..] not give an infinite recursion????
How can i better understand the haskell?

```
sqrtSums :: Int
sqrtSums = length ( takeWhile (<1000) (scanl1 (+) (map sqrt[1..]))) + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

### Laziness turns lists into streams

Lists in Haskell behave as if they have a built-in iterator or stream interface, because the entire language uses lazy evaluation by default, which means only calculating results when they're needed by the calling function.

In your example,

```
sqrtSums = length ( takeWhile (<1000) (scanl1 (+) (map sqrt[1..]))) + 1
```

it's as if `length` keeps asking `takeWhile` for another element,
which asks `scanl1` for another element,
which asks `map` for another element,
which asks `[1..]` for another element.

Once `takeWhile` gets something that's not `<1000`, it doesn't ask `scanl1` for any more elements, so `[1..]` never gets fully evaluated.

### Thunks

An unevaluated expression is called a *thunk*, and getting answers out of thunks is called *reducing* them. For example, the thunk `[1..]` first gets reduced to `1:[2..]`. In a lot of programming languages, by writing the expression, you force the compiler/runtime to calculate it, but not in Haskell. I could write `ignore x = 3` and do `ignore (1/0)` - I'd get 3 without causing an error, because `1/0` doesn't need to be calculated to produce the `3` - it just doesn't appear in the right hand side that I'm trying to produce.

Similarly, you don't need to produce any elements in your list beyond 131 because by then the sum has exceeded 1000, and `takeWhile` produces an empty list `[]`, at which point `length` returns `130` and `sqrtSums` produces `131`.

Comment: My comment got a bit too lengthy so I made it an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Haskell evaluates expressions *lazily*. This means that evaluation only occurs when it is demanded. In this example `takeWhile (< 1000)` repeatedly demands answers from `scanl1 (+) (map sqrt [1..])` but *stops* after one of them exceeds `1000`. The moment this starts happening Haskell ceases to evaluate more of the (truly infinite) list.

We can see this in the small by cutting away some pieces from this example

```
>>> takeWhile (< 10) [1..]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Here we have an expression that represents an infinite list (`[1..]`) but `takeWhile` is ensuring that the total expression only demands *some* of those countless values. Without the `takeWhile` Haskell will try to print the entire infinite list

```
>>> [1..]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24Interrupted.
```

But again we notice that Haskell demands each element one-by-one only as it needs them in order to print. In a strict language we'd run out of ram trying to represent the infinite list internally prior to printing the very first answer.

Comment: how can it be when the second argument from takeshile is what is returned from scanl1? isnt map sqrt[1...] called with scanl1?

Comment: No idea what you're asking, sorry. Can you rephrase?

Comment: Kelvin: `scanl` also produces a lazy list. It only consumes as much of `map sqrt [1..]` as is necessary to produce the elements demanded of it.